# Rails Ransack gem: search for multiple values by using only one select option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I use ransack gem and I have a select field **status** with multiple options

```
status_collection = %w(failed partial successful)
```

```
<%= search_form_for @q, :url => validation_path(:anchor => 'list'), :class => 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :status_eq, options_for_select(Validation.status_collection, @status_eq_selection), {}, {:class => 'form-control'} %>
<% end %>
```

in my controller:

```
def show
    @q = Validation.where(report_id: params[:id]).search(params[:q])
   @validations = @q.result(distinct: true)
end
```

I'd like to merge the options `failed` and `partial` together in one select option `failed` so that if I search for `failed` then ransack should also search for `partial` and merge both search results.

How can I make ransack to search status attribute by select option `failed` and also for attribute `partial` so that I have a merged result of `failed` and `partial` by searching only for `failed`.

Comment: Are you saying that when user select `failed`, you want to search for both status `failed` and `partial` but work normally for other status?

Comment: yes, exactly. maybe there is an easy ransack way to do it?

Comment: Not really, I think you need to update your ransack params when status is failed.

Comment: is there a way to concatenate the query with an OR, so that one can search for "status like failed OR partial"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in the comments, we can do it this way (not tested):

```
  before_action :adjust_ransack_params, only: [:show]

  private

  def adjust_ransack_params
    # Only change it if the status_eq is failed
    if params.dig(:q, :status_eq) == 'failed'
      params[:q].delete(:status_eq)
      params[:q][:status_in] = %w(failed partial)
    end
  end
```